# Why doesn't work my slideshow? Why my pictures disappear?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

Here is my code: http://codepen.io/lionelbogdanvagrad/pen/EyJoXk. I think this is easier to see my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 slide">

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/marea_neagra.jpg" class="image_slide">
          <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/mare.jpg" class="image_slide">
          <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/inside-home.jpg" class="image_slide">
          <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"><</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">></a>

      </div>
      <br>

      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      </div>

      <!--<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6">


      </div>-->


    </div>

  </div>


  <script src="js/script_slide.js"></script>
```

My main problems: 1. My images disappear.
                  2. My circles doesn't appear below the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I not quite understand what your problem is. The images you try to load don't exist in codepen server, that's why it doesn't work.

I edited the images `src` attribute to some random google images and it worked fine to me in firefox. [See pen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjNXKZ).

Try explaining more about the problem: what browser are you using? Are you getting any error logs in the console (press F12 to see) ?